# How to specify parameters for the executable file in a StartupTask

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

When desktop applications set to run on startup, they usually start minimized to system tray. The common approach to implement this behavior is an special parameter for the executable when adding a shortcut to the Startup folder or registry:

```
MyApp.exe /startminimized
```

I need the same thing in a converted desktop app. Thanks to the [StartupTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.startuptask), I'm able to run the executable of the app on startup:

```
<desktop:Extension
    Category="windows.startupTask"
    Executable="MyApp.exe"
    EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
    <desktop:StartupTask
        TaskId="MyStartupTask"
        Enabled="true"
        DisplayName="Some Arbitrary Name" />
</desktop:Extension>
```

However, I'm not able to find a way to set an argument for the executable so that my app knows it is running from startup and starts minimized.

I should be able start another executable which starts my app minimized but I'm looking for a more elegant approach to directly run the app minimized and keep the startup impact low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to specify a parameter for startup task today unfortunately. It is an open work item on our backlog.

As you point out, a possible work around is to launch a different EXE that then launches your app in the desired mode.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wanted to make sure there is no way to implement that before choosing the different EXE approach.

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate between start menu tiles, and regular app launches? If so, please ask a new question and we'll get you an answer to this. Thx!

Comment: Almost three years and this is still not implemented?

Comment: Over four years and this is still not implemented?

Comment: Any updates to this? Is a different EXE still the only way of doing this?

Comment: 6+ years and I'm still looking for a solution...
I wonder if .bat would work. If it's just EXE file, that's the worst solution

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan mentioned, currently there is no native support for [shortcut arguments](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-shortcut.html) but tools like Advanced Installer and others handle this stub (different EXE) behind the scenes, saving you some precious time.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*