# Detect launch by UWP startupTask extension

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I successfully got a Centennial app to auto launch at logon using a `StartupTask` inside `appxmanifest` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940683/uwp-app-start-automatically-at-startup/39646263#39646263). But I need to detect that that was how it was launched (as opposed to a user launching it manually.

How is that achieved?

I was thinking of using the [StartupTask class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask) for that, but couldn't find anything helpful there.

(While on the subject - how would I even use that class in a .net, since the reference to its assembly is not available for .net? See [my other question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849937/startuptask-class-is-not-recognized).)

Comment: See [How to specify parameters for the executable file in a StartupTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835631/how-to-specify-parameters-for-the-executable-file-in-a-startuptask).

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Thanks. (+1 for your question there.) Though I'll still wait to see if someone finds a way to just detect a startupTask launch (without parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this currently is by using a dedicated EXE for the StartupTask extension (i.e. different EXE from your application's entrypoint).

This way you know when you are being launched as StartupTask, and you can then launch your actual application with appropriate parameters from there.